# how to malloc array of structs using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have got a struct:

```
struct line{
  bool isValid;
  int tag;
  int block;
};
typedef struct line* L;
```

I want to setup an array of `struct line*` with the name set.

That is to say I want to initialize `L set[];`, and then I want to declare an array of the set `L* cache[]`.

So in a function `cache_new(int numSets, int numLines)` I want to initialize them using `malloc()`, how can I do that? New to C, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use `calloc(numSets, sizeof(line))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is declared with `[]` then you cannot dynamically allocate it. The `[]` mean the array will be automatically or statically allocated.

To dynamically allocate some structs  that are zeroed, you should do:

```
struct line *set = calloc(num_lines, sizeof *set);
```

With dynamic allocation, the array itself does not have a name, however using the pointer `set` which points to its first element, you can still access all the array members.

I'm not exactly clear on what you are asking about `cache`, but perhaps it is supposed to be:

```
struct line **cache = calloc(num_sets, sizeof *cache);
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_sets; ++i)
    cache[i] = calloc(num_lines, sizeof *cache[i]);
```

Please don't use pointer typedefs, they make the code hard to read. You can `typedef struct line Line;` if you want. And it doesn't really matter whether you do `calloc(N, size)` or `malloc(N * size)`.

Then you can access those arrays using `[]` notation, e.g. `cache[3][5].tag = 7;`

Comment: Quite a few `calloc()` implementations check for integer overflow.

Comment: @ninjalj yeah, and it can be faster too on some operating systems

Answer (score 0):

```
L cache;
var = (L)malloc(n * sizeof(cache[0]));
```